# How to hide Firefox titlebar in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, firefox, gnome-shell, titlebar

I am running Gnome-shell 3.2 in Ubuntu 11.10. Is there a way to hide the firefox title bar and make it like Chrome's ? I would need the min/max buttons in tab-bar. There was a tutorial in webupd8, but that was with compiz.

Comment: Related: [On Ubuntu 18.04 can I hide the Firefox title bar AND still see the close/minimize/maximize icons?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039360/480481)

Answer (score 16):

> **Notice:** HTitle is now discontinued, you can find an archive on [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20171031125831/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/htitle/) for historical reference.

You could use [HTitle Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/htitle/) to hide title bar.
This can be used **only with GNOME 3**.

Comment: The addon site currently says it was discontinued. :(

Comment: @LiveWireBT, I don't think that extension is no longer required since Firefox UI in full screen mode has been changed.

Answer (score 8):

I wondered how to do this as well and found that I do not need the title bar in any window if it is full screen in order to safe some pixels, so I did some changes to my metacity-theme-3.xml

/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml

```
<frame_geometry name="max" has_title="false" title_scale="medium" parent="normal" rounded_top_left="false" rounded_top_right="false">
    <distance name="left_width" value="0" />
    <distance name="right_width" value="0" />
    <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
    <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
    <distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="0"/> <!-- 
                            This needs to be 1 less then the
                            title_vertical_pad on normal state
                            or you'll have bigger buttons                               -->
    <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
    <border name="button_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
    <distance name="bottom_height" value="0" />
</frame_geometry>
```

With the "Menu bar" unticked, it just looks like Chrome. :)

There is also a Gnome 3 extension for this: [Pixel Saver](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver).

PS: I can also recommend the [GNOME 3 theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adwaita/?src=search) for a consistent look and feel (scroll bars etc).

Comment: But what about the minimize and close button

Comment: I never minimize windows (I just move them to other workspaces) and I close windows using shortcuts such as `Ctrl+Q`.

Comment: Pixel Saver was exactly what I was looking for in Gnome Shell.  I use Super+up/down/left/right to maximize/unmaximize/move to left or right half of the screen. Alt+F4 to quit. No need for minimize/maximize buttons (for me - I understand it doesn't answer OP's question)

Comment: That **Pixel Saver** extension was what I was looking for, very good!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:
Install this extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/hide-caption-titlebar-plus-sma/

- It'll show that is not compatible with our version, still click Add to Firefox and install.

All credits to WebUpd8:
[http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/firefox-4-get-tabs-in-title-bar-like.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npmoM.png)

[image: My Desktop]

Comment: This addon is now listed as compatible for Linux. You can also easily disable the orange menu button and the windows like close buttons if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

As of September 2019, this functionality is built into Firefox:

1. Right click empty space on the tab bar
2. Select "Customize..."
3. At the bottom of the window there is a "Title Bar" checkbox. Uncheck it to hide the title bar.

[image: screenshot showing the Customize Firefox tab]

Answer (score 2):

As the global menu extension in gnome-shell doesn't work with firefox, you have to make do with the firefox extensions.

There is an extension called "Mozilla Labs: Prospector - LessChrome HD 7" which shows the navigation bar only on mouse-over. It works quite well (works also very well with unity).

You can get it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-lessChrome-HD/?src=userprofile

Additionally, in View -> Toolbars, unmark "Menu Bar" and mark "Tabs on top"

Your Firefox window should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it still doesn't answer my question to hide the title-bar. I have Hide Caption Title Bar extension installed, but doesnt seem to work in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I am also facing this problem..Does anybody has any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good workaround [here](http://lightningismyname.blogspot.com/2011/09/saving-vertical-space-in-gnome-3.html).  It provides a keyboard shortcut for a fullscreen mode in which the Firefox bars are preserved.

Steps:

1. Open 'System Settings' (under the user menu top-right on the screen)
2. Select 'Keyboard'
3. Click on the 'shortcuts' tab
4. Select 'Windows' group of shortcuts
5. Click twice on 'Toggle fullscreen mode'
6. Type a shortcut (I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)

It's not perfect, but it does 90% of the job.

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility -> Check "Hide title of windows when maximized"

[image]