# Can I hide the Firefox title bar AND still see the close/minimize/maximize icons?

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, titlebar, window-buttons, csd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I realize with GNOME, or its extensions, I can do things like hide the title bar. However, I want to hide the title bar and still see the windows management icons like on Mac OS and Windows.
[image: Mac OS Example]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Firefox version 60 comes with an inbuilt client-side decoration (CSD) option which gets rid of the title bar but keeps the window control buttons (minimise, maximise, close).

If you have Firefox 60, go to "*Customise*" screen and disable "**Title Bar**" option at the bottom.

[image]

Then you should see something like this:

[image]

---

As a side note, the [pointy white corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ozl.jpg) that appear after turning off the '*Title Bar*' option, can be removed by the following steps:

1. Open `about:config` in a new Firefox tab.
2. Accept the risk and continue.
3. Type `mozilla.widget.use-argb-visuals` in the search field.
4. Check that '*Boolean*' is selected.
5. Click the '**+**' button to add the preference setting.
6. Restart Firefox.

Source: [article on OMG! Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/fix-firefox-rounded-corners-gnome)

Comment: This is fantastic!!! +1. Can I do the same in Thunderbird?

Comment: @user000001 I don't think it's been implemented in Thunderbird yet :(

Comment: The white corners on the top bar are annoying, is there no way to make them transparent?

Comment: @JAB Maybe they will go when the community theme is officially released.

Comment: @JAB Using a GTK+ theme which has *doesn't* have rounded corners for windows would be one possible way.

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](https://github.com/franglais125/no-title-bar), it solved my problem.
This is how Firefox looks after I installed it:

[image]
The close/minimize/maximize buttons are near (on the right of) the power icon (top right of the screen, they only show when you move the cursor there But you can modify that on **Tweak Tools >Extensions >No Title Bar** after you install it).

Comment: That's a big improvement, thank you. I have another extension which combines the dock and top panel into one (I really hate that wasted space), and it's working somewhat in conjunction with that. It's not ideal but I think your suggestion is the best possible for the moment. https://i.imgur.com/5owYCDv.png P.S. Thank you for taking the time to answer questions here, people like you improve the community and Ubuntu :)

Comment: You can modify the position of the **close/minimize/maximize** buttons as you want via **Tweak Tools >Extensions >No Title Bar** after you install it

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I every other position got glitchy presumably due to conflicts with my other fairly fundamentally changing behaviour extension.

Answer (score 4):

I use the GNOME Shell extension [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) for this.

When a window is maximized, this extension removes its title bar and places the minimize, maximize and close buttons in the top bar.

[image]

Comment: Ghostery gathers data now, there are good alternatives like uMatrix