# how to change behaviour settings in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: appearance

How can I change behavior in Ubuntu 18.04.There is no title bar with tabs disappeared in Firefox. There is no title bar for any option only i have is a firefox drop down tab with option to quit.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039360/on-ubuntu-18-04-can-i-hide-the-firefox-title-bar-and-still-see-the-close-minimiz

Comment: For sure - are you using Full-Screen mode? Does `F11` help?

Comment: F11 does not help, title bar disappeared  only i have a drop down tab to quit firefox