# How to remove drag tab in corner of firefox window

Tags: windows, firefox

There's a little grey area in the corner of my Firefox browser. I believe it's meant for dragging, but I have a key combo for that, and would like to reclaimed that little grey space.

[image]

How could I get rid of that little grey area? I remember finding a solution to this in the past, but upgrading to Firefox 65 seems to have resurfaced this nuisance : (

So, found my user browser chrome settings:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); 

.titlebar-placeholder[type="pre-tabs"],
.titlebar-placeholder[type="post-tabs"] {
  display:none !important;
}
```

For some reason this isn't working after upgrading to Firefox 65.

Also, I disabled an extension that manages tab groups, restarted the browser and all that, but it wasn't the culprit.

Comment: right-click and `Remove from Toolbar`?

Comment: That's Greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, solved this one. Firefox seems to have updated class names for the tab space draggable area things.

Here's the updated css:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.titlebar-placeholder[type="pre-tabs"],
.titlebar-placeholder[type="post-tabs"] {
  display: none !important;
  width: 0px !important;
  max-width: 0px !important;
}

.titlebar-spacer[type="pre-tabs"],
.titlebar-spacer[type="post-tabs"] {
  display: none !important;
  width: 0px !important;
  max-width: 0px !important;
}
```

Old naming convention above, and new one below. My display none and width 0 are probably a bit redundant.

Also, for those who don't know, this file should be named `userChrome.css` and should go in a folder called `chrome` that you create inside of `~.mozzilla/firefox/random-lettersi432789fd.default`

There are better instructions than mine for how to edit the userChrome.css file out there.

Comment: Note that on Quantum you need to go to about:config and enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` for userChrome.css to be picked up.

Comment: I would rather have a firefox logo there. can update the css with it?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I don't have enough rep. I don't think I have an answer, but here goes.

I don't have that little gray space you have, neither in full screen nor in a smaller window dimension. It seems more like a hidden tab, and I found [this related page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1130511), where the suggestions would be:

- it might be related to an Add-On (like the OP finds out);
- it might be related to problems with the sessionstore.js file in the profile folder that stores session data. You can find it in Help -> Troubleshooting Information -> Profile Directory -> Open Directory ([info](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox))

Hope it helps anyways.

Comment: It does help! I found the user profile with my browser chrome settings... updated my question with details...

Comment: You should be able to comment now as well : )

Comment: @Costa I don't think it's got anything to do with these. It seems from the screenshot that you have "Title Bar" disabled for Firefox (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039360/480481)). In that case it is a "*feature*". You have guessed correctly, it's meant for dragging as you have no title bar to click&drag.

Comment: Boo : ( I have the drag option checked in the firefox customize thing. And the grey corner thing goes away when the window is fullscreened.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Evident from my toggling it anyhow. But, if this was always the case, how did I solve this in the past? Perhaps there was a theme...

Comment: @Costa By past if you mean "long back" then it was probably a different issue. This "feature" was introduced in Firefox v60 last year.

Comment: I fixed this when I got this laptop about 5 months ago. I mean, maybe it wasn't me who fixed it, but I went to click on my mail and it wasn't there. The grey boxed showed up right after restarting after a firefox update.

Comment: @Costa Sounds like that update upgraded your Firefox to a version with this feature.

Comment: I remember that grey drag corner tab thing. This isn't the first time I've dealt with this.

Comment: Class names changed in firefox. Answer posted.